# what is the difference between econometrics and causal inference?

Tags: causalimpact

Econometrics is a science concerned with designing statistical models on data to answer the same questions as Causal science, so why are they not a single science?!

Answer (score 1):

### Causal Inference is a theoretical discipline, Econometricians apply the theory

Econometricians apply causal inference methodology to economic questions, just as they apply other tools from statistics or mathematics. Tools from causal inference are also applied in fields such as Medicine, Epidemiology, Finance, or Machine Learning.
Causal inference is more general than econometrics, so it makes sense to draw a distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will notice that Econometrics was developed within business schools and economists, unlike Causal Science which originated in a multi-disciplinary environment and is used in Health-Care, Policy-Making, and Business. While both mean to ask the same question but the key difference is that Causality Math is not meant for Observational Data where the scientist does not have the option of direct interference with the phenomena being researched.